# Hole in road bike tire

Tags: tire

This is 700x25 continental Ultra Sport II

I noticed there are two holes in both tires, and wonder if this is a manufacturing fault, or simply a wear indicator?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, those are wear indicators.

[The change is noted by retailers](https://www.westernbikeworks.com/product/continental-gatorskin-700c-road-tire-wire-bead):

> **Note**: Continental has added wear indicators to all Continental
>   Gatorskin tires. These small divots in the tread surface are
>   intentional and are not a sign of a factory defect. Once the rubber
>   wears to the point where the divots are no longer discernible, you'll
>   know it's time to replace.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tread wear indicator, and is present on all  modem continental tyres.

When the indicator disappears, it is time to replace your tyre.

see link directly from Continental:  http://conti-tyres.co.uk/tread-wear

Answer (score 1):

Highly likely to be a wear indicator. The Conti Grand Prix 4000s have them as well.

Comment: I've had these on my tires Grand Prix 4000 sII (perhaps a bit smaller) from the day I got them.  I've ridden them a couple thousand kilometers and haven't experienced any problems.